# Panel.repaint() doesn't seem to be refreshing panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

I'm having some issues repainting a JPanel on my GUI with default values.

The code I'm using right now is below, again, I'm not used to, nor really knowledgeable about java code, so forgive me for making rookie mistakes:

```
private void btnResetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    ...

    pnlWagens1 = new pnlWagens();
    UpdateGUI();
}                                        

private void UpdateGUI(){
    pnlWagens1.repaint();
}
```

So far I've tried the above code, as well as setting the JPanel to null, repainting, inserting a new instance of the panel, repainting again.
Nothing so far has been fruitful, as in the end, I'm still stuck with the old panel (and it's values) being shown on my GUI.

Basically, I make a panel with a green background initially, make the background red, then resetting the panel to have a green background again. However in the end, after hitting Reset, it still shows the old panel with the red background.

Any insight as to what I may be doing wrong/overlooking would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. You might very well solve the problem yourself by simply trying to isolate and expose the bug.

Comment: To translate the above for brevity: I don't see your error in the code above suggesting that it's in code not shown. First you must isolate the error, hence the need for a [mcve].

Comment: The only possible issue is that you're creating a new pnlWagens object, so perhaps you're not updating the correct one -- but hard to say.

Comment: I was updating the correct one, but as NESPowerGlove said, I needed to re-add the panel into my Frame in order for it to update its reference

Comment: Perhaps. It probably would be cleaner to not swap JPanels at all but instead change the state of the panel already there, call repaint() and have it draw a different image based on its state. This would be much simpler to code and involve much less overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is all the relevant code (and that `UpdateGUI` doesn't use `add` or `remove` with the panel reference you have there), then changing what object `pnlWagens1` refers to in your local class won't change other references that still refer to the old object. The old object `pnlWagens1` is still referenced by Swing in another location, from when you originally called `add` on some container.

What you need to do is to `remove` `pnlWagens1` from the container, change `pnlWagens1` like you are doing now, re`add` `pnlWagens1` to the container, and call then call both `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container.

Comment: That did the job just fine! I actually hadn't thought of removing it from the container, I honestly believed the reference would simply update when changed. Thank you!

Comment: @Yorrick No problem. In Java, references are passed by value, if you call a method and pass a reference, the method actually gets a copy of the reference.